# Problem with style on GWT Designer

Tags: css, gwt, styles, gwt-designer

I'm trying to create a login view with GWT Designer. I have the styles using twitter bootstrap.

I have this structure

[image]

I have this result

[image]

This padding and margin are killing me, I have all css with padding and border set to 0 but it makes no difference...and I have also set those properties on GWT Designer to 0.

I'm running the application directly with Eclipse, I'm not compiling it yet.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**I just test on tomcat, same thing**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used my HTML inside HTMLPanel and changed the inputs for the corresponding on GWT